# xml ae template not sourcing from module

Tags: xml, maya

I'm trying to use an xml AETemplate file for a custom scripted node I created in a module I have created in maya. Here's the contents of the module file.

```
+ mayaseed 0.6.2 /projects/mayaseed 

icons: graphics
scripts: scripts
```

I have tried adding the AETemplate file to the `scripts` directory but they don't show up in maya (mel AETemplate files work if they are here). I have also tried creating an `AETemplates` subdirectory in the `scripts` directory but it doesn't get found here either.

I've tried adding the following line to the module file:

```
MAYA_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_PATH +:= scripts
```

Has anyone any thoughts on how to make maya modules work with xml AETemplate files?

Comment: Have you checked inside a running maya to make sure that (a) your module is loaded and (b) does getenv MAYA_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_PATH show your path changes?  The parser for modules is very finicky and fails silently, so your env var may not be getting set at atll. You've probably seen this: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2012/07/distributing-files-on-maya-maya-modules.html but it's good reference if not

Comment: Maybe MAYA_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_PATH := scripts if the var is not already set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually due to the blank line on line 2, after the module definition all statements must appear in the lines directly after with no blank lines. So in this case:

```
+ mayaseed 0.6.2 /projects/mayaseed 
icons: graphics
scripts: scripts
MAYA_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_PATH+:=scripts
```

works just fine